# windows 10 system tray app crashing after several hours of running. What might be the cause?

Tags: python, winapi, systray, win32con

I really want to add more context but at the moment I'm just lost. When I click the link to show what line it failed on it points to this (' win32gui.PumpMessages() ') I can say it seems to occur after an hour or so of the computer in a standby state. Any and all help/berating of me is appreciated. I just need help. Thanks

Below is a snip of the area it failed on.

```
        window_class.lpfnWndProc = message_map  # could also specify a wndproc.
    classAtom = win32gui.RegisterClass(window_class)
    # Create the Window.
    style = win32con.WS_OVERLAPPED | win32con.WS_SYSMENU
    self.hwnd = win32gui.CreateWindow(classAtom, self.window_class_name, style, 0, 0, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                      win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 0, hinst, None)
    win32gui.UpdateWindow(self.hwnd)
    self.notify_id = None
    self.refresh_icon()
    t = Timer(01.0, self.Deskinfo_update_version)
    t.start()
    win32gui.PumpMessages()
```

below is the error:

```
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
Python runtime state: initialized

Current thread 0x00003f48 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\johns\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ftplib.py", line 192 in putline
  File "C:\Users\johns\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ftplib.py", line 201 in putcmd
  File "C:\Users\johns\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ftplib.py", line 274 in sendcmd
  File "C:\Users\johns\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ftplib.py", line 401 in login
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 206 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 226 in download
  ...

Thread 0x00001758 (most recent call first):
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 129 in __init__
  File "C:/Users/johns/PycharmProjects/Deskinfo_sys_tray/main.py", line 506 in <module>

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

Comment: Exit code `0xC0000409` is `STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN`, and the error message does say a stack overflow occured.  That is most commonly caused by an uncontrolled recursive loop that eats up stack space until it overflows. What is on line 226 of `main.py`?  That line is being repeated many time in the error message, which may indicate that is a recursive function call that is not ending its loop correctly.

Comment: I think I have narrowed down the issue. I have a Download function that is trying over and over. looping like you just mentioned. I'm sure I can resolve it from here. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Remy Lebeau comment is correct this is due to a looping try statement that is causing the crash.